# Is there a standard webpage resolution for mobile phones?

Tags: mobile, resolution

Most designers use 1024x768 as a baseline for website development.  That allows them to use css grid systems like 960 & blueprint to easily outline content.  Is there similar baseline resolution for designing for mobile phones?

The majority of users will be using iphone, android, and blackberry phones.

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031266/mobile-and-desktop-screen-size-statistics)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

320 by 480 is the common screen resolution for new mobile devices.

[iPhone Website Compatibility](http://www.firstscribe.com/blog/2007/06/is-your-website-apple-iphone-compatible.html)

[Android Display Metrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html)

That being said if you want to support the majority of mobile devices, you may want to support multiple resolutions.

Comment: Are those values up-to-date? Two years later?

Comment: @OlivierPons I'm going to *guess* not.

Comment: The mobile world has exploded since this was originally posted, giving us a plethora of screen sizes. Understandably there's a huge array of sizes to build to, but does anyone know the most *typically viewed* or *median* screen size nowadays?

Comment: As far as I can tell, even the HD mobile screen will actually display the website at 320x480px, unless user has no-scaling and similar option enabled (which is not enabled by default). You'll get surprising effects if you assume that screen size is equal to pixel resolution of the device.

Comment: I'd worry about the device width, considering that 320 is still accepted, and 360 too (320 is the width of all iphones up to date of this comment including iphone 5, and 360 is some standard like Samsung phones) as an additional note the android documentation updates constantly so the above link about android display metrics will never be obsolete

Answer (score 12):

[This website](http://screensiz.es) is super handy. An up-to-date database of various devices and their screen specs.

Comment: you can also test how will website look using quirktools page, http://quirktools.com/screenfly/, it has some default screen resolutions, but you can also use a custom one. If you combine the chance to test the media queries here with the device info posted by @luke, we can get a very clean end result :)

Comment: Well, that http://screensiz.es/ website was up-to-date, but seems to have stuck in time. No new phones in there.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using apache ApacheMobileFilter can help to determine the actual device screen size

Answer (score 2):

You can

1. get the screen sizes for the devices you plan to support,
2. Create say, 2-3 versions of your site and detect useragent string and direct user to one of these sites.

With android, iphone and blackerry devices there is not large difference in a screen sizes. With a litle foresight and design you may be able to have all these handset work on one mobile website (for example it would be fair to say that the width would be 240 pixels or greater and design accordingly)

However if you plan to go further than there these platforms there is a world of hurt awaiting you, (J2ME, BREW, Symbian, WinMo and 120x160, 176x220 screen sizes etc)

Answer (score 2):

I've found https://www.mydevice.io/#compare-devices to be the best site for determining this kind of thing. I was looking for the same and found this question via a Google Search, but most of the other websites mentioned above give you *device pixels*, not *CSS/JS pixels*, which is all that really matters in web development.

Sure, an iPhone 8 Plus may have 1080 *actual pixels* across its narrowest axis, but that is completely irrelevant to the topic at hand, considering that those pixels are much, much smaller than your HD TV for example. I wanted to measure the width of the display in relation to *how a browser actually renders a mobile site* and mydevice.io gives you that, as well as the physical dimensions. Win win! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Simply, no.

Lots of information here. http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/

There are just too many devices with too many different screens to assume a common resolution. While it may be true that 320 x 480 can be found on many devices, it is by no means "common". You have to use flexible design principles and then use media queries or js detection to add a class to adjust your display to the proper dimensions. This is part of what makes mobile so difficult to wrangle right now.

Answer (score 1):

yes there are 1024 x 960 x 800 x 768 x 640 x 480 x 360 for resposive web design sizes - better to go with percentages for avod this

Answer (score 1):

I write games for mobile devices. In my code I position everything by percentage as it will always be the same, plus I also use a var to adjust how many pixels they have then set my resolution to suit You can do pretty much the same with *css* and a few different image size's in your resources.