# Mobile and desktop screen size statistics

Tags: breakpoints, responsive-design

Where can I find statistics on mobile and desktop screen sizes?

I'm making a responsive site and specifically what I'm trying to find out is whether there is a size gap between the majority of phones and desktop and tablet users where I can put a breakpoint. I think that there should be but know I should test my assumptions.

So just to be clear, I want phones to have one set of styles, and tablets and desktops to have another set.

Thanks

Comment: EG If I put a breakpoint at 600px wide, presumably almost all desktop and tablets would be larger, and nearly all phones would be smaller?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I just finished doing a responsive business website ( https://plus.google.com/101258044853419629282/posts/GejAf734nP6 ) and here is what I can tell you - the breakpoint is definitely not 600px!

Here are the facts (in terms of CSS and @media queries):

1. 1366px desktop width just surpassed 1024px as the most popular size: http://techcrunch.com/2012/04/11/move-over-1024x768-the-most-popular-screen-resolution-on-the-web-is-now-1366x768/
2. Still, on tablets, iPad with its 1024x768px is the most popular.
3. iOS Safari is sane and always reports proper viewport, ie. no matter if you have a regular iPad or Retina iPad, it will tell you it's 1024x768, similarly iPhone will tell you it's 320x480.
4. Android browser has more problems, since screens vary on this platform. For example, Nexus One has a 480x800px screen, but at 254ppi (pixel ratio 1.5) the viewport reported to CSS is actually 360x600. Even funnier Galaxy Nexus has a 1280x720px screen at 316ppi (pixel ratio 2.0, like Retina), reported viewport is 360*640.

Exception is Chrome Beta on Android 4.0, in landscape mode it has a bug and seems like it reports the viewport width as 1280px on that Galaxy Nexus, making it very difficult to not conflict with desktop CSS.

**Conclusion**

I personally used a breakpoint of 768px screen width, namely: I treat iPad in landscape as desktop, and I assume minimum desktop size is 1024px. But I could also assume it's 800px, like in the old days. Then, I treat 768px specifically for iPad portrait, since non-retina iPads have a lot of space, it's not quite small-screen yet. Then, everything less than 768px I call a small-screen smartphone.

For maximum optimisation you could use interim breakpoints at 640px, 600px, 480px, 360px, 320px and even 240px (low-low-end androids) but it's probably a good practice to make it totally %-based below 768px so it fits automatically.

**UPDATE**: one useful breakpoint I found is 810px - the width of an iframe in a Facebook tab. Helpful when you create FB apps and want to reuse your webapp code.

Comment: I didnt make it clear in my question but by mobile I really mean just phones, tablets I want to treat as desktop. It seems like the smallest width for a tablet is 768. So if I target widths under 768 for my 'mobile' stylesheets, can I safely assume no tablet devices will get these styles? Thanks

Comment: Judging by Wikipedia ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices#Tablet_computers ) the smallest sane tablet is indeed 768 width. I see some smaller screens on that list, but you can't really call it a tablet. So, if you set the breakpoint at **max-width: 767px** then sane tablets will display desktop version in both landscape and portrait. The same for tablets with width 800px and pixel ratio 1.0. Anything smaller or with higher pixel ratio will display mobile version. Also, I don't believe there is a smartphone on the market that is 800px & pixel ratio 1.0, only 1.5 or more

Comment: Thanks for your answer but whats a 'sane tablet'?

Comment: Sorry, just my wording for a tablet that makes sense. On that Wikipedia list I see tablet screens like 1024x600, 800x480 or 400x240. In portrait mode, with pixel ratio 1.0, these devices would have 600px, 480px and 240px width respectively. And that's definitely not a tablet size, it's a phone size. So even though they are called "tablets", in portrait mode they should use the mobile version of the website in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

For the *latest* resolution stats change the date range in this url:
http://gs.statcounter.com/#resolution-na-monthly-200903-201401

On projects I've built we have media query break point on 1024px width as this is the width of iPad 1, 2 & Mini everything below that is "Mobile" and everything above is iPad+Desktop.

This is how the @nytimes developers are doing it.
see: JavaScript Jabber Podcast 093: http://javascriptjabber.com/093-jsj-the-new-york-times-and-javascript-with-eitan-konigsburg-alastair-coote-and-reed-emmons/
Where they describe this at 10:40.

For a more comprehensive list of device resolutions:
http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/21/responsive-web-design-with-physical-units/

As always ***it depends*** *who* you are targeting.
If you are building a site/app for **kids** (many of whom will have a **low-end android**) you may need an "ultra-mobile" version with a break point at 320px (width).

Answer (score 0):

960 x 800 x 768 x 640 x 480 x 360 are the sizes you must follow for responsive web design

Comment: iPhones have 320px width

Answer (score 0):

If one looks at [statcounter.com](http://gs.statcounter.com/) and compares the numbers with sources like [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) then can be skeptical about that how they got the numbers.

If you wanna get a real stats, plz visit this site: 
[browser display](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp),
[high screen resolution](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_resolution_higher.asp)

Comment: w3schools is a horrible recommendation, and I wouldn't trust a thing they have. Only thing they are useful for is the occasional syntax check. statcounter has said exactly how they get their stats, and it is pretty straightforward. http://gs.statcounter.com/faq#methodology