# ResponsiveGridSystem 1.6% = 20px: Why?

Tags: css, responsive-design, grid-layout

I'm looking into using the [ResponsiveGridSystem](http://www.responsivegridsystem.com) and on the site they have the following information regarding column margins:

> A margin of 1.6% gives you about 20 pixels on a standard monitor, but feel free to go large to suit your content.

Nowhere on the site does he explain the math or reasoning behind this bit of information. For starters, 1.6% *of what* equals 20px?

Comment: `0.016x = 20` -> `1/0.016 * 0.016x = 20 * 1/0.016` -> `x = 1250`.  Note that it says `about 20 pixels`, but looking at standard resolutions it's simple enough to assume they're talking about 1280 pixels wide.  A test of `1280 * 0.016` shows that it's equal to `20.48`, which is `about 20 pixels`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For starters, 1.6% of what equals 20px?

probably  the full horizontal resolution of the screen. The assumption here seems to be that that resolution is predominantly 1280px. Different available statistics on the issue are available, and they have different outcomes (as they will measure different audiences at different points in time.) [This article](http://techcrunch.com/2012/04/11/move-over-1024x768-the-most-popular-screen-resolution-on-the-web-is-now-1366x768/)  has a different resolution coming out on the top.

Related discussion: [Mobile and desktop screen size statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031266/mobile-and-desktop-screen-size-statistics)

Comment: Note: in the website, there's a 1200px-wide wrapper around the 3 columns because of `.maincontent { max-width: 92.3em }` so it'll make the assumption true for any screen wider than 1200px, sure enough.