# Attempting to hide and show images depending on device width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am new to responsive web design and am attempting to hide a current large image and show a new small one when the screen width is less than 480px wide.

This seems to work well when I shrink the width of my desktop browser, but when I navigate to the page on my mobile phone it is still displaying the large image still.

The code I'm trying:

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="lrgimg" id="lrgimg" alt="" />
    <img src="smlimg" id="smlimg" alt="" />
    <p>Some text , font size will change depending on device width.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    margin-right:0 auto;
    margin-left:0 auto;
    padding:10px;
    width:80%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#smlimg{
    display:none;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
#lrimg{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}

/* media queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){

    #lrgimg{display:none;}
    #smlimg{display:inline;}

    p{
        font-size:30px;
    }

}
```

I assumed `max-width` was enough to satisfy most phone screen widths but apparently even though the screen widths have stayed the same the resolutions have increased hugely.

My question is: Is there a standard `@media` query that I can use that will satisfy most modern mobile phone browsers?

here is a [demo](http://www.chrismepham.com/sites/test/livesearch.html)

Comment: Common troubleshooting.. it appears as if you don't have a viewport set. Set one, and it should work on mobile devices.

Comment: @JoshC could you expand on the `viewport` thing please?

Comment: Alright, place something like this in the `head` section of your page.. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: @JoshC that doesn't appear to help in this instance, but thanks I'll look up viewport

Comment: According to JoshC comment, you could also include `maximum-scale=1` in the `content` attribute: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` maybe that would help?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your screensize, 480px may still be too wide.  (If the screen size IS 480, it won't break until `@media screen and (max-width: 479px){` because a screen width of 480 is still included in `@media screen and (max-width: 480px){`

More statistics here: [Mobile and desktop screen size statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031266/mobile-and-desktop-screen-size-statistics)