# Ignore image through css

Tags: css

I'm using the following code with javascript to generate a blurred canvas element, that I use as backgrounds all around my site:

```
<div class="bg" data-src="demobilleder/njartists.jpg" id="bgc"></div>
```

This works without problems on desktop, but really make most tablets struggle (which are using the same template, RWD)

Can I somehow cleverly disable this through CSS? I know I can do a display:none, but the processing are still made. As there are media-queries I might use, so I'm able to substitute the ID or anything else that makes the image-processing stop?

My only other option is to do some device-sniffing, but since media-queries work fine for anything else I wonder if some CSS3 specs might fix this for me :)

Comment: Exactly! Use can use `media-query` for setting the `image` to `display: none;`

Comment: @Alexdn: But that wont help me. The browser still tries to process the image which is stalling the browser. I've tried to substitute the image url but eventhought theres no image the script still runs. Can I insert a new ID with the Content:? That would properly invalidate the line as not 2 ID's are allowed, causing the script to return an error (and therefore not try to do any process)?

Comment: Can you show us how you do that in your `css`?

Comment: @Alexdn: My issue is that I don't know if its possible, but the new various CSS3 selectors can do quite a lot, so I was thinking if this is possible. I'm using the following media-query to target Ipad-only: http://jsfiddle.net/rqmykk3a/

Comment: Google for **breakpoints**, or maybe visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031266/mobile-and-desktop-screen-size-statistics

Comment: @Alexdn: I don't need breakpoints, that already works.

Answer (score 1):

No.

JavaScript selects items from the DOM, not from the visible portion of it. So even if you try to hide it with CSS and media queries, JavaScript will still run and process it behind the scenes.

The solution is to check **[`window.innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.innerWidth)** and listen to an **[`window.onresize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onresize)** event.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I know too. So thats why I cannot use Display:none, I'm looking into if its possible to insert an ID through CSS (content:). If so, the JS cannot grap the ID correct and therefore will bypass it. I can insert a new image through CSS, but eventhought putting in an empty image it stills tries to process (the empty) image.